# Undefined error in build version with electron

Tags: javascript, build, electron, runtime-error, electron-builder

I have an electron app, the app is working when I am running:

```
npm run electron-dev
```

I am creating a `build` folder using `react-scripts`:

```
yarn react-scripts build
```

Than I am trying to build it using electron builder with the command:

```
yarn electron-builder -c.extraMetadata.main=build/electron.js
```

This is working well and I am getting a `dist` and a `build` folders with the compiled app and a build.

But when I am clicking the app I am getting:

[image: Error Image]

> A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
>   Uncaught Exception:
>   undefined: undefined

---

[Compilation success messages](http://txt.do/1qf5e)

When running the app via `electron-dev` (on the `build` folder or on the `public` folder) I am getting no errors, but I am getting 3 warning messages, 2 from firebase - `"When deploying Firebase apps to production, it is advisable to only import the individual SDK components you intend to use."`, `"Warning: This is a browser-targeted Firebase bundle but it appears it is being run in a Node environment."` and 1 about security `"Electron Security Warning (Insecure Content-Security-Policy) This renderer process has either no Content Security Policy set or a policy with "unsafe-eval" enabled."`.

---

**TD;DR**: How can I understand where the error is coming from and why, if the error shows only `undefined: undefined`?

Maybe through try and catch but than how can I display it on the error I am getting?

---

I'm working on Mac OSX (But it does not looks like this is the problem), I am using `opencv4nodejs` which takes a long time to compile, also I am using some json files to store app data using `electron-json-storage`.

Comment: It appears that the problem is indeed in `opencv4nodejs`! Yet I still do not know how to fix the problem.